# Whenever Eola fights at Reachcliff cave the game crashes

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Everything goes ok, but when Eola begins fighting, a bit after the game will crash.
I was able to prevent the crash by selecting her in console and typing:

```
setunconscious 1
```

When the fight ends I type

```
setunconscious 0
```

If I do not do that, it is 100% guaranteed that the game will crash. This tip can probably be used on similar situations, despite this being the first time I've see it happen.

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Are you using any mods? Or have you used mods? Skyrim is ... buggy. Have you used other console commands before? Like ressurect? All that is pretty buggy on npcs and the game.

Comment: @Ids I use like 150 mods, it seems to bug only when she shoots lightning bolts, but not the 1st one, it is after a few.. when I prevent her AI from "thinking" it wont crash! but then, she wont play either...

Comment: With that many mods there is a high chance of something going wrong. I would just accept setting her to unconscious and carry on.

Answer (score 1):

I kept her waiting outside of the cave instead of going in. After you finished the enemies inside, she will come inside without fighting and the quest will move on without crashing.